# TensorFlow reuse variable with tf.layers.conv2d

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to make 2 conv layers share the same weights, however, it seems the API does not work.

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.random_normal(shape=[10, 32, 32, 3])

with tf.variable_scope('foo') as scope:
    conv1 = tf.contrib.layers.conv2d(x, 3, [2, 2], padding='SAME', reuse=True, scope=scope)
    print(conv1.name)

    conv2 = tf.contrib.layers.conv2d(x, 3, [2, 2], padding='SAME', reuse=True, scope=scope)
    print(conv2.name)
```

It prints out

```
foo/foo/Relu:0
foo/foo_1/Relu:0
```

Changing from `tf.contrib.layers.conv2d` to `tf.layers.conv2d` does not solve the problem.

It has the same problem with `tf.layers.conv2d`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.random_normal(shape=[10, 32, 32, 3])

conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(x, 3, [2, 2], padding='SAME', reuse=None, name='conv')
print(conv1.name)
conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(x, 3, [2, 2], padding='SAME', reuse=True, name='conv')
print(conv2.name)
```

gives

```
conv/BiasAdd:0
conv_2/BiasAdd:0
```

Comment: for the first example why is reuse true even on the first conv?

Comment: @Steven I've tried all combinations to put reuse=True, but none of them to be effective. Could you help to give a short example to how make the weights to be sharing by using tf.layers.conv2d ?

Comment: I usually do it by hand i.e. create the weights and then pass them in.  Then I have the weight variable that I can reuse by simply using the same variable.  I can show an example of that?

Comment: In the first conv2d layer `conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(x, 3, [2, 2], padding='SAME', reuse=None)`, Should the `reuse` argument be `None`?

Comment: conv1 and conv2 are tensors which are different, but their weights (trainable variables) are the same (shared)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the code you wrote, variables do get reused between the two convolution layers. Try this :

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.random_normal(shape=[10, 32, 32, 3])

conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(x, 3, [2, 2], padding='SAME', reuse=None, name='conv')

conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(x, 3, [2, 2], padding='SAME', reuse=True, name='conv')

print([x.name for x in tf.global_variables()])

# prints
# [u'conv/kernel:0', u'conv/bias:0']
```

Note that only one weight and one bias tensor has been created. Even though they share the weights, the layers do not share the actual computation. Hence you see the two different names for the operations.

Comment: Note that you can set `reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE` so that you don't have to set it to `False`/`None` for the first call then `True` for subsequent ones. This keeps you from needing a special case for the first call.