# Tensorflow and Variable Scope - How to reuse scopes correctly?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensor

I re-designed a GAN which I have previously made with Keras. No Problem so far, however I notice that my model doesn't train correctly depending on the way I implement the scope reuse. Maybe someone could help me understanding what is happening:

**Working version:**

```
with tf.variable_scope('g/h0') as scope:
    reuse_scope = scope if reuse else None

    h0 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(
        z, 
        4*4*512,
        activation_fn=None,
        reuse=reuse_scope,
        scope='g/h0'
    )
    h0 = tf.nn.relu(h0)
```

**Not Working version:**

```
with tf.variable_scope('g/h0') as scope:
    if reuse:
        scope.reuse_variables()

    h0 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(
        z, 
        4*4*512,
        activation_fn=None
    )
    h0 = tf.nn.relu(h0)
```

*Both version lead to a working network, however the second one lead to a network that never updates. And I don't understand why the first version lead to a correct situation.*

In TensorBoard, the graph appears quite different depending on the version I pick. I suspect the gradient to backpropagate incorrectly.

Is there any way doing this with the second version ? I find it a lot more understandable.

Comment: My guess (though I have little experience with reuse) is that you should give `reuse` a `boolean` (wether you want to reuse variables from another scope) and not the scope name

Comment: If you precise *reuse* then you need to precise the *scope*. Then I don't understand the point of writing reuse_scope

Comment: Plus, I think the `scope` parameter is not linked to the `reuse` parameter, it is just the name of the scope used internally. See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py#L350

Comment: So what  *scope.reuse_variable()* is useful for if I don't need to use it?

Comment: It seems that it is useful if you declare twice a same variable in the same scope as you can see in this doc: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/variable_scope  (But why would you do that? I don't know...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you should try this way of defining your scope:

```
 reuse = ... # True or False 
 with tf.variable_scope('g/h0') as scope:
    h0 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(
        z, 
        4*4*512,
        activation_fn=None,
        reuse=reuse,
        scope='fully_connected',
    )
    h0 = tf.nn.relu(h0)
```

If you set reuse as `False`, you fully connected layer will be created "as usual". If you set it at `True`, no additional parameter will be created but weights and bias will be *reused* from another scope (with the same name and where variables with the same name have been created, of course).

- The `reuse` parameter must be `True` or `False` (or `None`, naturally)
- The `scope` parameter has nothing to do with `reuse`. It is just the internal scope name. For example, if you set `scope = 'g/h0'`, your weight parameter inside the fully connected layer will be `'g/h0/g/h0/weights:0'` but if you do not set it, it will be `'g/h0/fully_connected/weights:0'`.

A similar concern is addressed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42862300/tensorflow-reuse-variable-with-tf-layers-conv2d). It is roughly the same context as in your question, except that a conv2d layer is used and that the scope is not set explicitely.

**EDIT:**
I do not know if it is a bug or something normal but to use the `reuse=True` variable in `tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected`, you need to specify the `scope`...

The complete working example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
## A value for z that you did not specify in your question
z = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (2,1))

## First fully-connected layer with ut result
with tf.variable_scope('g/h0'):
    h0 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(
        z, 
        4*4*512,
        activation_fn=None,
        reuse=None
    )
    h0 = tf.nn.relu(h0)

tf.global_variables()
# Returns [<tf.Variable 'g/h0/fully_connected/weights:0' shape=(1, 8192) dtype=float32_ref>, <tf.Variable 'g/h0/fully_connected/biases:0' shape=(8192,) dtype=float32_ref>]

# Second layer ith  resuse = True
with tf.variable_scope('g/h0'):
    h0 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(
        z, 
        4*4*512,
        activation_fn=None,
        reuse=True, scope = 'fully_connected'
    )
    h0 = tf.nn.relu(h0)

tf.global_variables()
# Returns [<tf.Variable 'g/h0/fully_connected/weights:0' shape=(1, 8192) dtype=float32_ref>, <tf.Variable 'g/h0/fully_connected/biases:0' shape=(8192,) dtype=float32_ref>]
# => the same parameters are used for both layers
```

Comment: It doesn't work => `ValueError: reuse=True cannot be used without a name_or_scope`

Comment: I have fixed your code, now it works. Could you tell me when `scope.reuse_variables()` is supposed to be used if I don't need to use it here ?

Comment: We edited as the same time I think. I am sorry but I do not know the actual use cases of `scope.reuse_variables()` (I am almost a beginner in tensorflow). Consider posting it as a new question

Comment: I'll do it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I defined reuse=True first, then:

with tf.compat.v1.variable_scope('layer_1'):
....
....
....
with tf.compat.v1.variable_scope('layer_2'):

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).