# Tensorflow is not reusing variables under scope

Tags: tensorflow

There is a lot of code when subset of a neural network layers is reused. I always used the following code, which can be found, for example, [here](https://github.com/carpedm20/DCGAN-tensorflow/blob/master/model.py):

```
def discriminator(self, image, y=None, reuse=False):
    with tf.variable_scope("discriminator") as scope:
      if reuse:
        scope.reuse_variables()
```

Also, when some layer has `reuse` parameter, it should also be inherited. But when I tested this, it does not work for me:

```
import tensorflow as tf


a = tf.placeholder(shape=(3,10), dtype=tf.float32)

def func(a, reuse=False):
    with tf.variable_scope("discriminator") as scope:
      if reuse:
        scope.reuse_variables()      
      b = tf.layers.dense(a, 10, name='dense1', reuse=reuse)
      print(b)
      return b

print(tf.__version__)
b1 = func(a)
b2 = func(a, reuse=True)
```

Output:

```
1.10.1
Tensor("discriminator/dense1/BiasAdd:0", shape=(3, 10), dtype=float32)
Tensor("discriminator_1/dense1/BiasAdd:0", shape=(3, 10), dtype=float32)
```

Tensorflow just created different scope without saying anything!

`with tf.variable_scope("discriminator", reuse=reuse) as scope:` does not help.

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49285112/how-can-you-re-use-a-variable-scope-in-tensorflow-without-a-new-scope-being-crea) I've managed to go one level down:

```
import tensorflow as tf


a = tf.placeholder(shape=(3,10), dtype=tf.float32)

def func(a, reuse=False):

    with tf.variable_scope('discriminator/', reuse=reuse) as scope:
      if reuse:
        scope.reuse_variables()      
      b = tf.layers.dense(a, 10, name='dense1', reuse=reuse)
      print(b)
      return b

print(tf.__version__)
b1 = func(a)
b2 = func(a, reuse=True)
```

```
1.10.1
Tensor("discriminator/dense1/BiasAdd:0", shape=(3, 10), dtype=float32)
Tensor("discriminator/dense1_1/BiasAdd:0", shape=(3, 10), dtype=float32)
```

Anything else just does not work. For example,

```
import tensorflow as tf


a = tf.placeholder(shape=(3,10), dtype=tf.float32)

def func(a, reuse=False):
    if reuse:
        s = 'discriminator/'
    else:
        s = 'discriminator'

    with tf.variable_scope(s, reuse=reuse) as scope:
      if reuse:
        scope.reuse_variables()      
      b = tf.layers.dense(a, 10, name='dense1', reuse=reuse)
      print(b)
      return b

print(tf.__version__)
b1 = func(a)
b2 = func(a, reuse=True)
```

ouputs `Variable discriminator//dense1/kernel does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope?`

the same for the code

```
import tensorflow as tf


a = tf.placeholder(shape=(3,10), dtype=tf.float32)

s = None

def func(a, reuse=False):
    global s
    if reuse:
      sc = s.original_name_scope
    else:
      sc = 'discriminator'
    with tf.variable_scope(sc) as scope:
      s = scope
      b = tf.layers.dense(a, 10, name='dense1', reuse=reuse)
      print(b)
      return b


print(tf.__version__)
b1 = func(a)
b2 = func(a, reuse=True)
```

Tested in both tensorflow 1.10 and 1.8. Does it mean that a lot of code from Github already does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself. According to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42862300/tensorflow-reuse-variable-with-tf-layers-conv2d) they do share the same weights, but the tensors on the graph are separate:

```
import tensorflow as tf


a = tf.placeholder(shape=(3,10), dtype=tf.float32)

def func(a, reuse=False):
    with tf.variable_scope('discriminator', reuse=reuse) as scope:
      b = tf.layers.dense(a, 10, name='dense1', reuse=reuse)
      print(b)
      return b


print(tf.__version__)
b1 = func(a)
b2 = func(a, reuse=True)


print([x.name for x in tf.global_variables()])
```

```
1.10.1                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Tensor("discriminator/dense1/BiasAdd:0", shape=(3, 10), dtype=float32)                                                                                                                                                        
Tensor("discriminator_1/dense1/BiasAdd:0", shape=(3, 10), dtype=float32)                                                                                                                                                      
['discriminator/dense1/kernel:0', 'discriminator/dense1/bias:0']
```